# Clearcase View name duplicated by appending @@.Why?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have created base ClearCase view named `codecountview`, it was created by `cleartool` command.

Now under `M:` drive, I am having 2 view (as follows) with the same configspec.

```
CodeCountView@@
CodeCountView
```

I did not create `CodeCountView@@`, but how it is added.  ( Note: It is a dynamic view.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CodeCountView@@` is a temporary directory meant to be be used as a local cache by ClearCase.

You don't need to bother with it: it will disappear soon.

Your dynamic view is on `M:\CodeCountView`, as detailed in "[About dynamic view access model (Windows)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_mvfs/c_about_dynaview_access_model_win.htm)":

[image: MVFS model]

Answer (score 1):

If it bothers you, you can force it to disappear by running

```
cleartool endview CodeCountView
cleartool startview CodeCountView
```

Comment: Thanks buddy . Nice information. I have no other way to appreciate you than make it as useful answer. Thanks to Stackoverflow for providing this option